# Rename Devices in V4L2?

Tags: usb, ubuntu-20.04, v4l2

I have 4 identical HDMI -> USB 3 capture devices, meant to feed a live broadcast.  That works just fine.  After some one-time trial-and-error on the initial install, the broadcast production software always keeps them straight.

However, we sometimes run a remote meeting with one of the same sources, and when I go to start the meeting, I get this:

[image]

I just happen to know, after some more trial-and-error, that I always want the second one in that list, but that's a bit of tribal knowledge that I'd like to get rid of.  Physically rearranging the USB plugs (while powered off) does not reorder the list shown, but does mess up the broadcast software.  And the capture devices themselves were already tied down by the time I discovered this, so it's a bit difficult to rearrange their inputs.  Besides, if one of them needs to be replaced, that could also throw off a carefully-ordered-but-still-automatic list.

Can I put a custom name in each of those slots, that survives a reboot, so that someone else can see what they're actually choosing?
Or even better, so that the web browser can pick that source automatically, since it seems to do it by the first match of the name?

---

Here's what the broadcast software shows me (notice the additional identifier for each one):

[image]

And here's the output of `lsusb`:

```
hrcc@hrcclivemedia:~$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2c99 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. FHD Capture
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c99 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. FHD Capture
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c99 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. FHD Capture
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2c99 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. FHD Capture
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 08bb:2902 Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0764:0501 Cyber Power System, Inc. CP1500 AVR UPS
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
hrcc@hrcclivemedia:~$ 

hrcc@hrcclivemedia:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 5000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=pl2303, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
hrcc@hrcclivemedia:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can't change it because what you see on the list is the name sent by USB device in their configuration descriptor. You can hack your kernel to change it.
If you are a power user you can hack your kernel by modifying USB subsystem source code or use eBPF (or kprobes/kretprobes) to modify USB subsystem. Also, you can try to hack libusb to eg. append a serial number to the name of the device.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that the displayed name actually came from the hardware itself.  I was just hoping for a software-rename like you mentioned with the serial number.  If it has to be a hack, then I'm not sure I'm up for it.  You sure there isn't a bit of code somewhere, already written, to do that?

Comment: This turned out to be an X-Y problem.  Instead of running the camera directly into the meeting, I have the production software feeding a copy of its output to a loopback device that I *do* get to name when I create it.  Then use that loopback in the meeting.